# How do I circumvent the same origin browser policy (CORS) using NODE JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, puppeteer, same-origin-policy

I have 2 websites. (mydomain1.com, mydomain2.com) What I need to do is make the first site (mydomain1.com) load, with puppeteer, and then change its URL to that of the second site without reload page. I know that it is prohibited by browsers, but how i will do it with node JS, i will can to manipulate some things in browser.

Those are the browser configurations:

```
    var browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        executablePath: executable,
        ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--enable-automation"],
    args: [
      '--disable-web-security',
      '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process',
      '--disable-site-isolation-trials',
      '--disable-features=BlockInsecurePrivateNetworkRequests',
      '--disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies',
      '--disable-features=CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure',

    ]
```

And this is my code

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('localhost/test.html')
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.domain = "example.com";
  });
```

But then return this error:
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'domain' property on 'Document': 'example.com' is not a suffix of '127.0.0.1'.

There is some way to configure my browser to ignore same origin policy?

Comment: I think you misunderstand how the world wide web works, in general. `change its URL to that of the second site without reload page` makes absolutely no sense in any context

Comment: Is this inside an iframe?

Comment: also, I always thought CORS has to do with XMLHttpRequest, Fetch, @font-face, WebGL textures, images/vidoes frames drawn to a canvas, or CSS Shapes from images  - none of which appears to be relevant to the question

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way with any browser.

A solution could be to use a web server with a 3rd domain `mydomain.com`, then configure it to have:

- `mydomain.com/domain1` redirect you to `mydomain1.com`
- `mydomain.com/domain2` redirect you to `mydomain2.com`

Now you can navigate to `mydomain.com/domain1` and load `mydomain.com/domain2` inside the page properly as they're both part of the same domain `mydomain.com`